# Can you upload files to S3 bucket from a static website hosted on S3 (without using any instances)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way of uploading files to an S3 bucket, using a static website as an interface (hosted on another S3 bucket)  without running any instances?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [S3 presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to upload objects using JavaScript.

But obviously you need some kind of backed (a **lambda function**) which is going to generate these S3 presigned URLs when needed, as they are only temporary.

Comment: well, if you are using lambda function then for just uploading the files you don't need a static website (obviously, you may be using the website for more than just uploading the files). But lambda function can be invoked directly through URL